# Destructuring a param defined within an interface

Tags: generics, reactjs, typescript, jsx, typescript2.0

I'm a little confused here as to why this doesn't work.  Can someone please explain why `plans` in the PricingComponent doesn't imply the typing from the defined interface.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Plans from '../data/Plans';

interface PricingProps {
  plans: {
    [index: number]: {
      id: number,
      unitLimit: string,
      ownerLimit: string,
      storageLimit: string,
    };
  };
}

const Pricing: React.StatelessComponent<any> = () => <PricingComponent plans={Plans} />;

const PricingComponent: React.StatelessComponent<PricingProps> = ({ plans }) =>
  <div />;
```

Comment: What version of TS are you using? It works for me on @2.0.3. Also, where are you getting your react typing?

Comment: @Paarth yes, I'm using 2.0.3 as well.  I use the `noImplicitAny` tsconfig `compilerOptions` prop which causes it to complain about implicitly being typed as any.  I just assumed that the type could be inferred though.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. I also have `noImplicitAny` on, and it's still working for me -- which is why I'm interested in your `react.d.ts`. Also, is it possible you've got your editor (vscode perhaps?) using 1.8.5 or some other version of TS?

Comment: @Paarth I'm using DefinitelyTyped @types definition for React 0.14.43.  However, I will say that I have some other errors in my project currently that I'm trying to resolve related to react definitions not being found.  It's possible this is related...

`ERROR in ~/node_modules/@types/react-router/lib/applyRouterMiddleware.d.ts
(4,43): error TS2305: Module '"~/node_modules/react/react".export=' has no exported member 'Props'.`

I have about 100 of these various errors related to the typings which is fairly clear they're not getting loaded properly.